# Conditional Formula: display text if cell contains

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to change the display text in a cell if the cell contains a keyword. For example, I have a column with many similar text strings:

```
Christmas Tree - School A
Christmas Tree - School B
Christmas Tree - School C
```

In the above example, I would want the cell to simply display "Christmas Tree"

I can't work the customer formula in conditional formatting to achieve this. Possible?

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet and include an example of the outcome that you are trying to achieve. FWIW, if a cell has a value in it, then you can only display _that_ value in _that_ cell - though you _can_ apply formatting. Even "conditional formatting" doesn't change the value, it just changes the formatting. But, you can use _another_ cell containing a formula/function/query/whatever to display a different value based on the value of the original cell and your criteria. For example, say Cell A1 = "School A Christmas Tree" - you might use Cell B1 to display your desired value.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A, "Christmas Tree"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "(Christmas Tree)"), A1:A))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.